# How to autofill text area base on combo box value on MS.Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010, expressionbuilder

I had problem when trying make form using MS.Access and i don't know how to make text area value same as combobox value like this picture:

[image]

Comment: Use the `AfterUpdate` event of the combobox.

Comment: can you tell me what i suppose to do using ```AfterUpdate ``` event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Me!TextItem.Value = Me!ComboItem.Value
```

Of course, use the actual names of your controls.